# what is the limitation to chain together multiple models in Design Studio? And any hardware specification for that VM?

Tags: acumos

Total how many number of the models we can chain together in the Design studio. Is it dependent upon the hardware configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fixed limit on the number of models in a composite solution in the Acumos design studio.  Please note that each child model is deployed as a separate docker container. So basic resource limitations such as runtime memory in the target deployment VM may be reached if you construct a large composite solution.

Are you asking about specific resources such as a GPU in the deployment VM? That really depends entirely on the models you use.

Also see the DSCE documentation: https://docs.acumos.org/en/athena/submodules/design-studio/docs/index.html